# Access WAMP on port 8080

Tags: apache, port, wamp

IIS is already installed on my server. I have configured WAMP to listen port 8080. Its working fine on the server's LocalHost when i access `[http://localhost:8080]`

But, when I try to access the website `[http://production.myurl.com:8080/]` it does not display the page and showing `"Connection timed out"` message. Is anything else I need to configure apart from the HTTP config?

Comment: Not a programming question.  Anyway, check port forwarding/firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are behind a firewall or a router you need to open the port in the FW or configure port forwarding in the router to your computer.